# Was Myxomatosis Man Made?

Tags: pathology, infectious-diseases

I can't seem to find any conclusive information about the origin of Myxomatosis. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myxomatosis)

> It was first observed in Uruguay in laboratory rabbits in the late 19th century. It was introduced into Australia in 1950 in an attempt to control the rabbit population.

However I find this passage unclear.

Was this a naturally occurring disease that we then used as a means of population control, or did we have a hand in its creation?

Comment: It was identified as a disease in 1896.  How do you think people were able to "create" viruses in 1896?

Comment: @layork That would depend what you mean by "create". As far as I'm aware, a virus present in rats doesn't mean that it is necessarily transferable to rabbits without modification.

Comment: Do you suggest that myxoma virus was first found in rats? @Pedr

Comment: Myxomatosis has natural origins in the wild rabbits of South America. In 1942 Aragao showed that wild Brazilian rabbits has acquired (not innate) immunity to the myxoma virus from a previous infection.